# How do I auth in google api with my credentials or special generated id and password?

Tags: php, google-api, google-oauth, google-calendar-api

I want to get all my events from my personal calendar. I have tried for hours all kind of auth types:
I did successfully auth with callback, where I should login to my google account and then google redirects back to my website. - but this is not what I need.
Also I have tried with default credentials, and on my surprise, I don't have access to my calendar, what kind of logic is this.

Basically, how its working for me in Spotify: in Spotify it is possible to generate client id and password in my account. After that I send HTTP with base64(client:password) in my header from my code and receiving token, which I use to query some entities.

But in google API I didn't find such solution. Maybe someone could advice how to authenticate?

Answer (score 3):

You could use the [Google client library for PHP](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/php/start/get_started).  It's marked `beta`, but I found it easy to use and it works just fine for simple Calendar use cases.

I put a [working example out on GitHub.](https://github.com/mikepatrick/php-google-calendar)

If you would rather code directly against the OAuth 2.0 APIs, I'd recommend checking out the [Google Developers OAuth 2.0 Playground](https://developers.google.com/oauthplayground).

- Select the `Calendar API v3` at step 1.
- At step 3, click `List possible operations` and select `List Events`.  Replace `{calendarId}` with your gmail.com email address.

This allows you to observe the auth flow, starting with the redirect back to your application after the user authenticates and grants permissions with Google:

```
GET /oauthplayground/?code=4/xxxxxxxxxxxZL-nxhM_kxxxxxxxxxQ HTTP/1.1
```

---

```
POST /oauth2/v4/token HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 233
content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
user-agent: google-oauth-playground
code=4%2FxxxxxxxxxxxxxxZL-xxxx_kxxxxxxxxxxQ&redirect_uri=https%3A%2F%2Fdevelopers.google.com%2Foauthplayground&client_id=4xxxxxxxxxx.apps.googleusercontent.com&client_secret=************&scope=&grant_type=authorization_code
```

---

```
GET /calendar/v3/calendars/user@gmail.com/events HTTP/1.1
Host: www.googleapis.com
Content-length: 0
Authorization: Bearer ya29.GlsBBUxxxxxxxxxxXo-dF-Kexxxxxxxxxxxx0j_owVSaxxxxxxxxxWG-Xxxxxxxxxl
```

Comment: thanks, for your answer. I successfully generated token through this Playground and was able to retrieve necessary data, but token expires after 3600 sec, and the checkbox "Auto-refresh the token before it expires." seems not refreshes my token automatically.

Comment: The auto-refresh token function is a feature of the playground, not of the token itself.  If you leave the playground open for an hour, it *will* make the necessary call to refresh the access token for you - you'll see the access token change.  In your application, you need to provide this logic yourself.  i.e. your application has to keep track of when tokens need refreshed and refresh them accordingly.  Note that refresh means "use a refresh token to get a **new** access token", not "make this access token good for another hour".

Comment: Thanks, for you answer, I saw your example before or similar code in examples from google, it's not bad, but actually your answer not answers what I really need, I still needed to authenticate once manually and than use refresh token. But as only you respond to me, I will give you bounty, but I will not accept it